# How to make JSON look pretty?

Tags: javascript, json, api, pretty-print, stringify

So I am trying to create an api and here is my code snippet

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');


const steamScrape = require('./steamScrape');

console.log()
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/steamScrape', (req, res) => {
    res.json(steamScrape);
});
```

This is a snippet of my json file:

```
[
   {
      "name": "asdasdadsa",
      "discount": "-40%",
      "price": "CDN$ 0.71",
   },
   {
      "name": "asdasd",
      "discount": "-40%",
      "price": "CDN$ 20.39",
   }
]
```

But this is how it looks when I run the server. How do I make it look pretty? I have tried using JSON.stringify() and that adds \n characters everywhere

[image]

Comment: you can install `json formatter` in your google chrome store

Comment: Your API is supposed to send data and formatting should be a concern of the front end involved. Usually a `<pre>` tag on an html page is enough to format it.

Comment: in chrome network tab, you have a "preview" tab when you click on the json request, this will pretty print too

Comment: The real question is, why do you want it to look 'pretty'...?

Answer (score 2):

try **JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2);**

Comment: Thank but it didnt work, it still shows \n characters everywhere